# update query sql table in yii

Tags: database, yii

How can I update row in table in yii? I am using the following code but it is not working

```
$sql = "UPDATE auth_assignment SET itemname = 'Authenticated' WHERE userid = $user->accountID";
$command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
$command->execute();
```

Comment: what is ur model name

Comment: And $connection is equal to `$connection=Yii::app()->db;` ?
Is the request working if you enter it directly in mysql?

Comment: yes it is working if I directly enter it in mysql. I have also set $connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `$user` is being converted to a string and thus the `->accountID` is not working.  You have two methods, one unsafe and one safe.

Unsafe - Add {} around the $user->accountID.
`$sql = "UPDATE auth_assignment SET itemname = 'Authenticated' WHERE userid = {$user->accountID}";`

Safer - Use a parametrized query:
`$sql = "UPDATE auth_assignment SET itemname = 'Authenticated' WHERE userid = :userid";

$command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
$command->execute(array(':userid' => $user->accountID))`

Comment: I had missed single inverted comma around $user->accountID due to which it was not working. But I liked your solution of safer query, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

ok I forgot to put commas around
    'user->accountID'